# Javascript with custom Google Map markers / drop animation

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I'm very much a novice at JS but I was hoping to get a custom map working. I've worked on two scripts rendering the map: [One with the drop animation (maptest1)](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/maptest1.html), [one with the custom markers (maptest2)](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/maptest2.html).

Individually, they both work great but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the animation **AND** the custom marker. I know that the `drop` and `addMarker` functions are doing the animation in [maptest1](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/maptest1.html). I've tried to integrate those functions with my code in [maptest2](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/maptest1.html), but I can't seem to make it work.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

**maptest1:** (drop animations)

```
var locations = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.578033, -122.288116, 1),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.675625, -122.304115, 2),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.681580, -122.355278, 3)
];
var markers = [];
var iterator = 0;
function initialize() {
  drop();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.63,-122.33),
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          mapOptions);
}
function drop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      addMarker();
    }, i * 200);
  }
}
function addMarker() {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locations[iterator],
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }));
  iterator++;
}
```

**maptest2:** (custom markers)

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
   overviewMapControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.63,-122.33),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
  setMarkers(map, studios);
}
var studios = [
  ['Mount Baker', 47.578033, -122.288116, 3],
  ['Ravenna', 47.675625, -122.304115, 2],
  ['Phinney', 47.681580, -122.355278, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapimages/image.png',
      new google.maps.Size(30, 52),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(15, 52));
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapimages/shadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(60, 52),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(15, 52));
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var studio = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(studio[1], studio[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: studio[0],
        zIndex: studio[3]
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

[If anyone is wondering, using Ryan's additions to the script here it working currently.](http://www.vitalitypilates.com/maptest.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add this to maptest1.html inside addMarker()

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapimages/image.png',
    new google.maps.Size(30, 52),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(15, 52));
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapimages/shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(60, 52),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(15, 52));
var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
    type: 'poly'
};
```

and change this:

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locations[iterator],
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }));
```

to this:

```
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    position: locations[iterator],
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    shadow: shadow,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
  }));
```

I *think* that will work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! You're amazing. I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours!

Comment: No problem, sometimes it takes a second set of eyes to figure things out :)

Comment: Last comma after shape: shape, is superfluous and may cause IE to barf.

Comment: @Ryan I *really* appreciate the input and for providing a perfect solution. I updated the OP with a follow-up. I don't want to abuse your generosity here, so no pressure.

Comment: @AndrewR : create a new question, I'd rather separate the questions so things aren't confusing for people reading this later.